# Cacti is ignoring hash marks in interface aliases

Tags: monitoring, cacti, rrdtool, graph

I'm attempting to set up Cacti to monitor a router's interfaces, and I'm having trouble getting the graph templates to show the information that I'd like.

Our interface configuration looks like this:

```
 interface GigabitEthernet3/6
  description WalljackNumber # Server info 
  no ip address
  no shutdown
  switchport
  switchport access vlan 116
  switchport mode access
  ip dhcp snooping trust
  spanning-tree portfast
```

The "Server Info" string is really just the machine name, and a short relevant description, such as "PolarSprings vmnic2". The important part appears to be that it follows the hashmark.

When I run snmpwalk, I get the proper output:

```
 IF-MIB::ifAlias.230 = STRING: WalljackNumber # Server info
```

But in Cacti, when I go into the graph templates and set the title to this:

```
 |host_description| - Traffic - |query_ifName| (|query_ifAlias|)
```

All that shows up in the graph is:

```
switchname - Traffic - Gi3/6 (WalljackNumber #)
```

Which strikes me as a little weird. What I suppose MAY be happening is that somewhere in the cacti stream, it's interpreting # as being a comment and stripping everything after, but I'm not sure.

I was hoping someone could tell me that this was a known documented behavior, or that I could change it in a setting that I wasn't aware of. The alternative answer is to change the delimiter from # to something else, but I've got over a thousand lit switchports on an old college infrastructure, and I'm not sure what else might be relying on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Complex on twitter found it for me.

The issue is that there's a maximum field length setting that was getting in the way.

As found at http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/faq.html#AEN2524, you go to Console, then Configuration/Settings, and alter Maximum Field Length to a more reasonable number, and it starts working shortly.